# Register component callbacks appropriate for current SDK version

Tags: java, android

I want to receive notifications for onTrimMemory when available (ICS+) and onLowMemory otherwise (> ICS).  My questions are the following:

1. Will the system allow me to define a class that implements an interface that is not in the current SDK as long as I don't instantiate it?  For example, defining `CallbacksICS implements ComponentCallbacks2` while targeting minSdk 8, for example, but checking the current SDK_INT before choosing what to instantiate and register.
2. Will onTerminate always get called when the application is ready to be cleaned up by the system?  I vaguely remember hearing in the early days that some of the Application life cycle methods aren't guaranteed to be called.

From my Application class:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        callbacksICS = new CallbacksICS();
        registerComponentCallbacks(callbacksICS);
    }
    else {
        callbacksLegacy = new CallbacksLegacy();
        registerComponentCallbacks(callbacksLegacy);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        unregisterComponentCallbacks(callbacksICS);
    }
    else {
        unregisterComponentCallbacks(callbacksLegacy);
    }
}
```